# MATLAB Code for a shadowed rician fading channel

Tags: matlab, channel, telecommunication

Hello I'm having some trouble understanding how to make a shadowed rayleigh fading channel

[image]

like the above picture.
What I'm trying to do is making a channel model where
Q = Q_los +Q_nlos where Q_los follows Nakagami, and Q_nlos follows a complex Gaussian channel (0,b)
The below code is what I tried

```
        hSL = sqrt(GL * (c / (4 * pi * fc * dSL))^2);

        %% Shadowed Rician Channel Generation
        % Nakagami Fading for LOS Component
        h_LOS_magnitude = randraw('nakagami', [m, omega], [numOfAnt, 1]) * hSL;

        % Complex Gaussian for NLOS Component (Magnitude and Phase)
        h_NLOS_component = (randn(numOfAnt, 1) + 1j * randn(numOfAnt, 1)) * sqrt(b) * hSL;

        % Combined Channel
        h = (h_LOS_magnitude + h_NLOS_component);

I'm confused if 
1. Do I have to consider the phase too?
2. h_LOS_magnitude = randraw('nakagami', [m, omega], [numOfAnt, 1]) * hSL; <- is this part OK?
```

```
    hSL = sqrt(GL * (c / (4 * pi * fc * dSL))^2);

    %% Shadowed Rician Channel Generation
    % Nakagami Fading for LOS Component
    h_LOS_magnitude = randraw('nakagami', [m, omega], [numOfAnt, 1]) * hSL;

    % Complex Gaussian for NLOS Component (Magnitude and Phase)
    h_NLOS_component = (randn(numOfAnt, 1) + 1j * randn(numOfAnt, 1)) * sqrt(b) * hSL;

    % Combined Channel
    h = (h_LOS_magnitude + h_NLOS_component);
```

```
I'm wondering if this would function as the channel below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G5kI.png)
```